# How to remove "xsd" from xsi:type string?

Tags: php, soap, xsd

I have created a `SoapVar` object:

```
new SoapVar($this->caseContainer(), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "CaseAmb", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
```

This is the result:

```
<ns1:caseDto xsi:type="xsd:n3:CaseAmb">
    ...
</ns1:caseDto>
```

I would like to remove the `xsd` from `xsi:type`. For example:

```
<ns1:caseDto xsi:type="n3:CaseAmb">
    ...
</ns1:caseDto>
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?